# How to search for a pattern within a String/Char array?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to look for a pattern in the input given by the user. And return the (start,end)position if found.

Eg:-

Input = `A B C D B C A D`

Pattern to look for = `D C A`

Output = `3,6`

The pattern need not necessarily occur consecutively.

It can be like D is at the start of the input, C at the middle and A at the end. - A valid scenario.

Two things I am confused about.

- How to take the input? As an array? If yes, then as a String or Char array?
- How do I look for the pattern?

Comment: your example is not clear. D C A not fount in your input

Comment: How is 3,6 a valid answer based on your input?

Comment: There's a catch here.
The pattern can occur with gaps. Not necessarily be consecutive.

Comment: then you can use a regex on the string

Comment: what if there are multiple occurrences? What would you like to return in case of - `A B D C X C A B A`?

Comment: Multiple occurrences can be like `A B D C X A D C A'.
In the scenario you mentioned,  it should return 2,6

Comment: No. I'm looking for DCA. It is 2,6

Answer (score 1):

The format of the input does not matter here: you can take both the string and the sequence as strings. The trick is deciding on an algorithm to use to solve the problem.

In this case, a greedy strategy will work:

- Read two strings, `S` (string) and `P` (pattern).
- Make two indexes - `si` for the string, and `pi` for the pattern, and set them both to zero.
- Search for the letter `P.charAt(pi)` in `S` starting at `si`. If the letter cannot be found in the substring from `si` to the end, then the pattern does not exist
- Otherwise, take the first occurrence of `P.charAt(pi)` in `S`, set `si` to that index plus one, and advance `pi` by one.
- If you reach the end of `P`, you are done
- Otherwise, go back to the search step, and continue processing until you either find a pattern, or exhaust the string.
- If you need to print the indexes for the sequence, add an array of indexes, and fill it out as you go. The length of the array should equal to the length of `P`.

Note that there may be multiple solutions to this problem. When a solution exists, this algorithm finds the first "lexicographic" set of indexes that solve the problem.

Comment: I'm using Nested For loops for this.
Any other better way ?

Comment: @R11G You need only one explicit loop for this - the one going through the elements of `P`. Finding the next match can be done by calling `S.indexOf(si, P.charAt(pi))` instead of an explicit nested loop.

Comment: Solved it using regex but I'm not able to solve with the Algo you suggested. Why is it a "greedy" strategy? Any special characteristic?